# link randon usando iframe

Tags: php, html

Estou com esse código abaixo e preciso que o link dentro do iframe mude a cada refresh da pagina e fiz da seguinte forma abaixo só que não funfou só funciona com link clicavel... como esta no código

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Link Aleatorio</title>
<script>
    var enderecos = new Array("http://www.terra.com.br", "http://www.google.com.br", "http://jbonline.terra.com.br", "http://www.lycos.com", "http://br.yahoo.com", "http://www.altavista.com", "http://www.hotbot.com", "http://www.buscopio.com", "http://oglobo.globo.com", "http://www.excite.com", "http://br.cade.yahoo.com", "http://www.mercadolivre.com.br", "http://br.weather.com", "http://www.buscape.com.br", "http://www.msn.com", "http://www.astrolabio.net")
    function linkAleatorio(){
       aleat = Math.random() * enderecos.length
       aleat = Math.floor(aleat)
       window.location=enderecos[aleat]
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--<a href="javascript:linkAleatorio()">LinkAleatorio</a>-->
<iframe src="<?php echo javascript:linkAleatorio(); ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"  scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplo em  [ideone](https://ideone.com/FUzloE)

obs: se retornar pagina em branco é porque o site não permite que seja exibido em iframe.

Já que sua tag tem PHP faça assim:

```
<?php
$enderecos = array("http://www.terra.com.br", "http://jbonline.terra.com.br", "http://www.lycos.com", 
"http://www.hotbot.com", "http://www.buscopio.com", "http://oglobo.globo.com", "http://www.excite.com", 
"http://br.cade.yahoo.com", "http://www.mercadolivre.com.br", "http://www.buscape.com.br", 
"http://www.astrolabio.net");

$result = (rand(0,count($enderecos)-1));
?>


<iframe src="<?= $enderecos[$result] ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

OBS: muitos sites não permitem que sejam exibidos em iframe (google, yahoo, oglobo etc...)

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou como o esperado.